# Adding Game Objects to list forever problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a prefab that I am adding to a list with timing in between for game functionality. However it never stops adding Game Objects.

In the **addToPath()** the for loop right there spawns 1 object every 2 seconds but if I change that to anyother number like **total** which is the total amount I want in the list it will add that many every 2 seconds.

```
 public class FollowPath : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int total;
    public GameObject enemyAi;

    public List<GameObject> enemy;
    private IEnumerator coroutine;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        print("Starting " + Time.time);


        addToPath(enemyAi);
    }

    private void addToPath(GameObject ai) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            StartCoroutine(WaitAndPrint(2.0f, ai));
            print("Before WaitAndPrint Finishes " + Time.time);
        }  
    }

    // every 2 seconds perform the print()
    private IEnumerator WaitAndPrint(float waitTime, GameObject ai)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            print("WaitAndPrint " + Time.time);
            enemy.Add(ai);
            // Works for Object in Scene and Prefabs
            Instantiate(enemy[enemy.Count - 1], new Vector3(1, 1, 1), Quaternion.identity);

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks unclear to me what you're trying to do here, but the problem is definetly that `WaitAndPrint` never finishes, it has a `while (true) {...}` that doesn't allow it to terminate. The loop is not spawning objects, `WaitAndPrint` is.

What you probably want is this:

```
public class FollowPath : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int total;
    public GameObject enemyAi;

    public List<GameObject> enemy;
    private IEnumerator coroutine;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        print("Starting " + Time.time);


        StartCoroutine(addToPath(enemyAi));
    }

    private IEnumerator addToPath(GameObject ai) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            WaitAndPrint(2.0f, ai);
            print("Before WaitAndPrint Finishes " + Time.time);
        }  
    }

    private void WaitAndPrint(float waitTime, GameObject ai)
    {
        print("WaitAndPrint " + Time.time);
        enemy.Add(ai);
        // Works for Object in Scene and Prefabs
        Instantiate(enemy[enemy.Count - 1], new Vector3(1, 1, 1), Quaternion.identity);

    }
}
```

Comment: After looking at this for so long I miss used my loops, makes sense now that I hear that